# Playwright: Trying to Get text from label but it returns Strange locator

Tags: typescript, playwright

Look at the attached pic[image]

Here is the inspect element
[image]
I am trying to fetch the WO No. When I click on WO No, I get following and I store it in **WONo**

```
  const WONo = page.getByLabel('WO No')
```

When I print it I get following, While to my understanding it should return **12204** as showin in the pink the pink area. Am, I understanding the whole thing incorrectly?

```
  Locator@internal:label="WO No"i
```

Any Hint/help will be appreciated. I am using typescript with plauwright.
BR

Comment: `page.getByLabel()` returns `locator`. Also, it searches for label tags, or the `aria-labelledby` element, or by the `aria-label` attribute and can manipulate the `input` attached to that label for eg to fill the input. See [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-get-by-label)

Comment: It's better to add differentiative class names or ids or even data-test-id which makes testing far more easier

Comment: @KiranParajuli Playwright recommends using roles over CSS classes/ids. See [best practices](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#prefer-user-facing-attributes-to-xpath-or-css-selectors)

Comment: @ggorlen it's not always feasible to use roles. how to get a particular submit button if there are multiple submit buttons in a row. Names can change more often than these items so it's always best to use IDs or unique class names.

Comment: @KiranParajuli Of course it's not always possible, but when it is feasible, it's generally a better option than IDs or CSS. Quoting the Playwright documentation: "Your DOM can easily change so having your tests depend on your DOM structure can lead to failing tests. For example consider selecting this button by its CSS classes. Should the designer change something then the class might change breaking your test." and "Automated tests should verify that the application code works for the end users, and avoid relying on implementation details such as ... the CSS class of some element."

Comment: OP might not be testing, they might be web scraping, which is a bit of a different scenario. They won't have the option to add test ids in that case. But I wouldn't make any recommendation against the standard approach without more context.

Comment: Using chained selectors like `'button.buttonIcon.episode-actions-later'` or `'.parent .child .episode-actions-later'` is highly fragile for the test. That's 100% right. But using `.episode-actions-later` can be very safe if the `className` is unique enough. If a developer needs some placement adjustments with the button, then too, they do not need to change the `className` and the test can be consistent although there is a change in the DOM structure.

Comment: @KiranParajuli it has returned following so Actually it didnt work



async inputValue(options) {
    return this._frame.inputValue(this._selector, {
      strict: true,
      ...options
    });
  }

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `get_by_label` is locator so you may need to do nested findings, get the input, and then read its value.

```py
const WONo = await page.get_by_label('WO No')

const WONo_value = await WONo.get_by_role('textbox').input_value()
```

Comment: it returns following

```
sync inputValue(options) {
    return this._frame.inputValue(this._selector, {
      strict: true,
      ...options
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean the `WONo_value` logs that?

Comment: Can you please post the whole `label` div in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `innerText()`, `textContent()`, `inputValue()`.

Or the same functions for `page.getByLabel('WO No').locator("input")`, if **innerText** doesn't work